# Help reaching the solution to the integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have the following equation:
$$
\frac{dR}{dt}=k_{o}(1-R)-k_{a}R
$$

and I want to integrate the equation, **whose solution is**:

$$
R|_{t}=\frac{k_{o}}{k_{o}+k_{a}}+e^{-(k_{o}+k_{a})t}(R|_{0}-\frac{k_{o}}{k_{o}+k_{a}})
$$

Now, I can get to

$$
R|_{t}=k_{0}(t-\frac{R^{2}}{2})-k_{a}\frac{R^{2}}{2}-C
$$

which I hope is correct, but I dont know how to proceed from here mostly to get to the exponentiation part (but I know how to compute C). Can you help me out please?

Comment: Hi @Moo. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: $dt=\frac{dR}{k_o(1-R)+k_a R}$, therefore $t=???$

Comment: i'm sorry but i think you should seriously review the fundamentals of how to solve seperable ODE's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of your **linear first order** differential equation will proceed as follows:

$$\frac{dR}{dt}=k_{o}(1-R)-k_{a}R$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=k_{o}-(k_{o}+k_{a})R$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}+(k_{o}+k_{a})R=k_{o}$$
The integrating factor in this case is $e^{\int (k_{o}+k_{a})dt }=e^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}$

So multiplying by the integrating factor, we get

$$e^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}\frac{dR}{dt}+(k_{o}+k_{a})Re^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}=k_{o}e^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(Re^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t})=k_{o}e^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}$$
$$d(Re^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t})=k_{o}e^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}dt$$
Integrating both sides w.r.t $t$, we have 
$$Re^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}=\frac{k_{o}}{k_{o}+k_{a}}e^{(k_{o}+k_{a})t}+C$$

Thus the general solution is $$R(t)=\frac{k_{o}}{k_{o}+k_{a}}+Ce^{-(k_{o}+k_{a})t}$$

The differential equation you have is of **first order** and hence your solution contains **one constant** of integration.

To uniquely determine the constant, you need a constraint known as a [boundary condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem). According to the condition given, it will become an initial value problem or a boundary value problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the variables R and t.

From the initial equation

$\frac{dR}{dt}= k_o(1−R)−k_a R$

Get all the R's on one side with the $dR$ differential and anything related to $t$ on the other side.
Doing this you get:

$\frac{dR}{k_o(1−R)−k_a R} = dt$

Now you can integrate this

$\int \frac{dR}{k_o(1−R)−k_a R} = \int dt$

This can be simplified a bit by collecting the R terms and the constants in the denominator

$\int \frac{dR}{k_o-(k_o+k_a)R} = \int dt$

This is in the form:

$\int \frac{1}{a+bR} dR = \int dt$